# Fastest way to flip the value of a boolean

Tags: rust, boolean, bit-manipulation

I am trying to find the fastest way to flip the value of a Boolean in rust? i.e.

```rust
false => true
true => false
```

For my application I do not care about the current value of the Boolean only that it is flipped. For my application (Sieve of Atkin - an improved version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes) this will need to be performed a large number of times so would be good to have it run as fast as possible. Currently my code is:

```rust
item[i] = !item[i]
```

Because, (as mentioned) the current value of item[i] is irrelevant I am sure there is a faster (possibly bitwise) way to do this. However, I'm a bit of a rust nubie and haven't been able to find it, can anyone advise me on a better way?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you not using bit-fields? I don't think you could do less then this instruction.

Comment: @Neil I'm using an array of Booleans. I'm pretty new to rust and low level in general so apologies if this is a stupid question but what is the difference between the two?

Comment: The indexing operation (`[]`) will probably cost much more than the boolean flip. `[]` contains bound checks, even in release mode. But if you use iterators instead, these bound checks are omitted. Anyway, I would be very surprised if the compiler, in release mode, was not able to generate the optimal code for `!` (xor or anything better for the specific processor).

Comment: @Pioneer_11 I have also never programmed in Rust, but I suspect the behaviour of the structure in cache is (packed) more important then micro-optimizing instructions.

Comment: For all optimization questions, the _only_ answer is: compile with `--release` and measure, _measure_, **measure**. For that you can use [criterion](https://crates.io/crates/criterion) which allows you to compare multiple implementations of a function.

Comment: Oh, and don't waste time "optimizing" code unless it does slow down your program. Use a profiler to find out where your program spends the most time, and only optimize those parts.

Comment: Fast or not, `my_long_bool ^= true` is pretty *short*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter. The compiler will outsmart you on this and pick the fastest method it knows. The exact syntax you use is not important. **However this is only the case when you remember to turn on optimizations.** You may think this is obvious, but it is an extremely common mistake. This is done using `--release` when building or running your project with cargo. If you forget this step, the compiler won't even attempt to speed up your code and timing code execution becomes meaningless.

What matters more is how you access the memory where the boolean resides. Try to keep memory you are working with on the stack if you are doing a lot of work on one value or small region at a time. Cache locality also means that it will be faster to read adjacent cache lines than jumping between places in memory. Memory is more likely to be in the cache if you accessed it recently or the CPU guesses you are about to access it.

There are also crates like `bit-vec` and `bitvec` which reduce each boolean to using a single bit. This is great for improving memory usage (8x improvement to be exact), but comes at a very small cost to performance. I would avoid the `bitvec` crate though. About a month ago I did some benchmarks and the performance was absolutely abysmal.

Do you need to work on a single boolean at a time? Try to work with entire words of memory if possible. Bitwise operations on a `u64` will likely take the exact same amount of time, but you get 64x the productivity.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like a cool idea. Not sure if I've got the skills to play around with it at the moment but I'll certainly keep it in mind.

Comment: What is the difference in performance between stack and heap? I was originally under the impression that stack memory has superior allocation and access speed to heap memory but when I asked a question about writing a function which would use an array of numbers with a length based on an input value (known at compile time) I was told that heap vs stack only mattered for allocation time and that I was better off using ```Vec::with_capacity()```

Comment: @Pioneer_11 The secret is that the stack is just another part of the heap. However the advantage is that you know it is essentially guaranteed to be in the top CPU cache so access times will be far faster. It is not unexpected to see the access time drop a full order of magnitude between the L1 and L2 caches. Once you start working with a portion of the heap it will get moved up into the higher cache levels giving you more comparable access times. However, the L1 cache typically only holds 8KB-64KB so it will likely be evicted to make way for different parts of the heap as your program runs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm coming over to rust from python so I haven't really dealt with this stuff before and by the looks of things I severely underestimated my ignorance of low level design. I think I've got some reading to do

Comment: It may seem daunting, but caching and these sorts of optimizations are not something you would normally put a lot of thought into. The compiler is almost always able to create a performant solution without any extra effort on your part. The main performance pitfall to look out for is unnecessary cloning of memory. It may be easier to only deal with owned values, but it might require a lot more allocation and copying of memory. If a function does not need to take *permanent* ownership of the data you likely do not want to pass it a `Vec<T>` or `String` (Try to use `&[T]` or `&str`).

Comment: @Pioneer_11 You may also find it helpful to use a profiler. If your machine uses an Intel CPU you then VTune is great option. You just tell it which executable to run and it can tell you exactly how much time each individual line of code contributed to your runtime. Just remember to add `[profile.release] debug = true;` to your `Cargo.toml` before building so it adds debug symbols to your generated executable. The debug symbols tell it where to find your code and which lines in your source files the compiled machine code instructions were built from.

Answer (score 2):

Since in Rust a boolean variable is represented as an 8 bit unsigned integer with 0 for false and 1 for true, the compiler can implement negation without a branch by computing the XOR of the value with 1.

That being said, while I'm not familiar with the Sieve of Atkin, at least for the Sieve of Eratosthenes, you really want to use bitfields rather than booleans. But the same trick can be used there to avoid a branch.

Comment: Thanks, I has made the (clearly mistaken) assumption that rust represented Booleans with a single bit. As a point of interest do you happen to know why rust uses u8's for Booleans?

Comment: @Pioneer_11 an `u8` can have an address and can be used a whole. Conversely, a bit needs a bitwise operation; you cannot have a single variable of type bit.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 It uses `u8` for the same reason we have padding and alignment on `struct` fields. If you want to fetch a bit, you need to first get the byte, then pick out the desired bit. It is just faster to give each boolean a full byte and avoid the shifting. Most types will only include one or two booleans at most so this just works better than going for maximum memory efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, I'm coming over to rust from python where I've not really had to worry about this stuff in the same way. Sounds like I need to have a bit more of a look at the guts of the language and some low level basics before jumping in.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 If you're new to Rust, "fastest way to flip a Boolean" probably doesn't belong on your top1000 list of things to learn about Rust. ;)